# why do not save pictures from the Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

**Add logo** to add a picture, and **Download** have to download, but it does not work 
(you can try it in to browser)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Up() { //upload
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image(),
    src = "http://chu93.aphp.fr/wp-content/blogs.dir/32/files/2015/10/LOGO-YOUTUBE.png";
  img.src = src;
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 480, 400);
  }
}

function download() { //download
  var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  this.href = dt;
};
downloadLnk.addEventListener('click', download, false);
```

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
</head>

<body onload="doCanvas()">
  <button type="button" onclick="Up()">Add logo</button>
  <a id="downloadLnk" download="img.jpg">Download</a>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="config.js"></script>
```

Comment: check developer tools console for errors regarding `tainted` images

Comment: but first, check the console in the snippet you posted, because it doesn't even work

Comment: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement'